# How to get Piwik into a data visualisation tool

Tags: data-visualization, matomo

I'm trying to find a way to import Piwik data into something more powerful than the built in reports. I was hoping to import it into googles data studio however it is asking for the database name and I'm not sure what that is.

Has anyone any experience in getting data out of Piwik and into tableau/google data studio/please suggest other tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you have executed the default installation, the name should be 'piwik'. However if you want to connect directly from Tableau you would need to know as well if you're running Piwik on MySQL or MariaDB.

About the data analysis, in my experience, having used Tableau and Pidgin, I would recommend to put your data in an intermediary database with an ETL process as I don't consider the Piwik database structure optimal for BI analysis.

Link with information of database structure: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/persistence-and-the-mysql-backend

PS: before trying to create custom reports or ETLs, I would check your Piwik version in case you've not migrated to the latest one, as from 2.x to 3.x they changed the database a bit (e.g. custom dimensions)